# Wheel Menu - Dynamically rows

Tags: javascript, css

I have a wheel menu in css/js and currently I have 8 menu elements. But I want 6 or 12
menu elements. I am tried few hours, but it's not working perfectly, when I add more or delete some div elements, it's buggy. How I can do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/b9f4x8d2/

I need help with this

```
function onMouseMove({ clientX: x, clientY: y }) {
                    if (!showing) return;
    
                    let dx = x - anchorX;
                    let dy = y - anchorY;
                    let mag = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    let index = 0;
    
                    if (mag >= min) {
                        let deg = Math.atan2(dy, dx) + 0.625 * Math.PI;
                        while (deg < 0) deg += Math.PI * 2;
                        index = Math.floor(deg / Math.PI * 4) + 1;
                    }
    
                    wheel.setAttribute('data-chosen', index);
                }
```

and this part:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 99%, 99% 0);
                    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 99%, 99% 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggestion requires additional modifications,
but it may provide a start.  It changes from 8 selections to 6.

The following are modifications to your fiddle code
and are NOT intended to be executed here.

```js
  const listeners = {
    1: () => {

    },
    2: () => {
            
    },
    3: () => {
            
    },
    4: () => {
            
    },
    5: () => {
            
    },
    6: () => {
            
    }
  };
```

```css
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(1) img {
   --rotation: 30deg;
   transform: scale(1) rotate(var(--rotation)) !important;
 }
    
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(2) img {
   --rotation: -30deg;
   transform: scale(1) rotate(var(--rotation)) !important;
 }
    
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(3) img {
   --rotation: -90deg;
   transform: scale(1) rotate(var(--rotation)) !important;
 }
    
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(4) img {
   --rotation: -150deg;
   transform: scale(1) rotate(var(--rotation)) !important;
 }
    
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(5) img {
   --rotation: -210deg;
   transform: scale(1) rotate(var(--rotation)) !important;
 }
    
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(6) img {
   --rotation: -270deg;
   transform: scale(1) rotate(var(--rotation)) !important;
 }
    
 .wheel[data-chosen="1"] .arc:nth-child(1),
 .wheel[data-chosen="2"] .arc:nth-child(2),
 .wheel[data-chosen="3"] .arc:nth-child(3),
 .wheel[data-chosen="4"] .arc:nth-child(4),
 .wheel[data-chosen="5"] .arc:nth-child(5),
 .wheel[data-chosen="6"] .arc:nth-child(6) {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: scale(1.1) rotate(var(--rotation)) !important;
   filter: brightness(150%);
 }

 .wheel .arc:nth-child(1) {   --rotation: -30deg; }
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(2) {   --rotation:  30deg; }
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(3) {   --rotation:  90deg; }
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(4) {   --rotation: 150deg; }
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(5) {   --rotation: 210deg; }
 .wheel .arc:nth-child(6) {   --rotation: 270deg; }
```

```html
<div class="wheel">
  <div class="arc"> Directory <br>Listing
  </div>
  <div class="arc"> Test 2
  </div>
  <div class="arc"> Test 3
  </div>
  <div class="arc"> Test 4
  </div>
  <div class="arc"> Test 5
  </div>
  <div class="arc"> Test 6
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey, thank you! its worked but i need to change the ```onMouseMove``` function, because its not working perfectly

Comment: Sorry, I did not look at that portion of your code.  I thought the main objective was to change the display from 8 to 6 or 12 selections.  What is the problem with the onMouseMove as I am not getting any errors?

Comment: when i move the mouse, its select automatically the menu point. but i don't know what i need to change for 6 menu elements.

Comment: fixed with this line ```index = Math.floor(deg / Math.PI * 3) + 1;```

Comment: Does that fix the 8 or 6 segment problem?  Or both?

Comment: Note that in index = Math.floor(deg / Math.PI * 3) + 1 what you need to divide by is half the number of items in the menu. So for 8 items (as in the original) it was 4, for the code in this answer it is 3 and for 12 items it is 6. You may find it easier to maintain if you define a const num (and CSS variable --num) as the number of items and use that in the various calculations.